# .htaccess makes subdirectory appear in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I've been searching for this but **I'm really newbie with .htacces (I find it a hell)** and I cannot get the way to solve this.

I have the *root* folder in my server, redirecting the default domain URL to the folder *"web"*. I have another folder, let's say *subfold*, and inside this, I have another folder: *mobile*.

What I want is that if someone types *www.adomain.com* it goes to *root/subfold*, without showing the *subfold*. I've done it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.adomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfold/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /subfold/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

However, when I go to *www.adomain.com/mobile* it shows in the URL *www.adomain.com/subfold/mobile/*

My aim is that if I go to the *mobile* subfolder, in the URL it should show *www.adomain.com/mobile*

*Obviously, I would like not to have to write a redirect everytime I add a subfolder, it it was possible.*

How should I do that?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting redirected because your accessing a directory without a trailing slash. The mod_dir module, on by default, will redirect the browser and add a trailing slash if someone tries to access a directory without a trailing slash. This is because there is a information disclosure issue with indexing directories. You can either turn this off:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

and risk having the contents of your directories get listed, even if there's an index.html file. Or add a bunch of rules to ensure there's a trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

# redirect for trailing slash:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.adomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfold/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfold%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.adomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfold/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /subfold/$1 [L]

# redirect for trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As you said, it was the slash that was messing the whole stuff.